# How to hide a background image during transition with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with transitions applied to the text input box. Two of which are "required" fields with a red star in the left hand corner. When you click the input box to see the transformation I want the star to vanish.

How do I achieve this?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
    input {
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        white-space: 7px;
        color: black;
        padding-left: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: width .5s; /* Safari */
         transition: width .5s;
     } 
    
    input:focus {
        height: 30px;
        color:#060;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
    
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
    
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
    
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
    
        box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,96,0.41);
        width: 250px;}
    
    .required{
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-image: url(star.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
    <form action="process.php">
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <ol>

    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="required" type="text" id="email" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input  class="required" type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </li>
</ol>
</form>
```

So how would I go about it?

Comment: Have you tried `:focus` - input:focus{ background-image: none;}

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what css code to use to get the star to vanish upon clicking. I can't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: When you click the input it gets the focus automatically, which will kick the css focus rule in action

Comment: I got it... used .required:focus {background-image:none;} Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your CSS part.

`View this`: http://jsfiddle.net/pt3s8nap/